# Styling input type="file" with a box shadow

Tags: html, forms, css

I am using javascript to add a red glow using CSS box-shadow to form fields that are incorrectly filled. I am running into a problem with my file input field, in Firefox the glow extends around the browse button and I am also unable to remove the default border.

Is there a way to achieve this with CSS?

Thanks.

Here is an example -

[image]

**HTML**

```
<input type='file' id='userfile' name='userfile' maxlength='80' class='form-input'/>
```

**CSS class being assigned**

```
.field-error { -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 5px #ff0000; -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 5px #ff0000; box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 5px #ff0000; border: none; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is not a standard way to achieve this, but you a kind of create a div around the file element give a box shadow to a div and use width to get around this, but again this will work only for firefox, since chrome has a different way of presenting the file upload element.

for example something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xd5hd/2/)

Comment: Thanks, I took this idea and created a div that has some padding and goes around the whole field. It seems to do the job in Firefox and Chrome so far.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the "Browse" button is completely inaccessible to CSS manipulation. You need some tricks to overcome this issue. I recommend you take a look at this article:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Or use jQuery alternative:

- http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle

Comment: Thanks, these are useful links. Not quite what I was looking to do but they'll be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime ago I faced a similar problem with inputs of type file. This is the best I could find: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Hope this helps you.

Update: there is also a jquery plugin to style input fields: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle